# server status command

Tags: opennms

How do I check the server status using command prompt?
I have installed opennms and it is working as expected in GUI mode. But I want to use it in a shell script and hence need a command to check a port on xyz server.

Comment: Why not use `nmap`, or `telnet`, ...?

Comment: Already using that. But someone told checking opennms status will be more reliable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very unclear. Do you mean you want, from the command-line, to see the results of an OpenNMS poll? Or do you mean you want OpenNMS to perform a custom check using a script?

If the former, you can set up notifications to receive server status through email or pager, or use a text-mode browser to view a node's status. If the latter, [the GpMonitor](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/GeneralPurposePoller) can do what you want.

Alternatively, if the test you want to do can be done in a language that BSF supports, you can use [the BSFMonitor](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/BSFMonitor) instead of the GpMonitor; it should be more performant by way of avoiding having to fork & exec.